# What is the different between Windows Form App and Windows Form App (.Net Framework)?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using VS2019 and want to create a WinForm app. What is the difference between Windows Form App and Windows Form App (.Net Framework) and which of these 2 options
should I choose?

[image]

Comment: I bet the second one is using .NET core as the driver. Check the project's Target Frameworks for clarity as it is lacking in the brief description given for each project type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about the different versions of .NET and .NET Framework, you can decide which one suits what you want to build:

> Developers use the .NET Framework to create Windows desktop applications and server based applications. This includes ASP.NET web applications. .NET is used to create applications that could run on Windows, Linux and Mac. It does not support creating Windows desktop applications on platforms other than Windows. Developers can write applications and libraries in VB.NET, C# and F# in both runtimes.

> What does .NET has the .NET Framework doesn't? .NET will receive new features and runtime improvements. It has better performance, and it has ability to have different versions of .NET deployed side-by-side on the same machine, create self-contained applications, and be completely independent on the environment you are running on and so on

> What does the .NET Framework has the .NET doesn't? It has some older API that will not be moved to .NET. And how do you choose for your new applications choose .NET for your applications that are only in maintenance mode and all the development is completed you don't want to touch that code it's completely safe to leave them on the .NET Framework and for existing applications that are targeting .NET Framework but are in active development you can make your call if they move them to .NET or leave them on the Framework you can evaluate benefits and porting cost and make the decision that is best for your application

**if you want to use the newest language features and runtime improvements you should choose to dotnet core**

You can also look at the following link:

- [.NET Core vs .NET Framework](https://stackify.com/net-core-vs-net-framework/#:%7E:text=Developers%20use%20the%20.,applications%20and%20server%20based%20applications.&text=NET%20Core%20is%20used%20to,applications%20with%20a%20user%20interface.)
- [.NET Core and .NET Framework - what to choose? | Desktop and .NET Core 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPWTdQ7rh2w)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project and you can see a (.Net Framework) which means it only works under Windows OS and creates applications only for windows. The other default template I believe is for .Net Core a cross-platform which runs in different OS.

Comment: WinForm won't run on other OS, even with .NET Core, it still rely on Windows-only APIs.

Comment: @Martheen in that case why they create a separate template for that which make no sense?

Comment: So people can migrate/create WinForm app that interact with modern libraries and new features available only on .NET Core

Comment: @Martheen that's what I am thinking after my comment, okay makes more sense now. thank you